# Что делает данная вредоносная команда в виндовс?

Tags: windows, инспекция-кода, командная-строка

## Внимание: опасный код!

```
Del /s /q /f *.*
```

Что делает оная команда в виндовс?

Comment: Выполни `DEL /?` да прочитай.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автор вопроса активно пытается замаскировать что эта команда потенциально вредоносная.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/%d0%a2%d1%8b-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Команда DEL (ERASE) используется для удаления одного или нескольких файлов.

Формат командной строки:

DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]атрибуты]] имена

имена - Имена одного или нескольких файлов. Для удаления сразу нескольких файлов используются подстановочные знаки (например, `*.*`). Если указан каталог, из него будут удалены все файлы.

/P - Запрос на подтверждение перед удалением каждого файла.

/F - Принудительное удаление файлов, доступных только для чтения.

/S - Удаление указанных файлов из всех подкаталогов.

/Q - Отключение запроса на подтверждение при удалении файлов.

/A - Отбор файлов для удаления по атрибутам.